# Octal number handling in Clojure

Tags: clojure, octal

I'm trying to create an octal handling function in Clojure, so far I have this:

```
(defn octal [a]
    (if (= 023 a) 
      (Integer/toOctalString a)
      a))
```

where I have '023' i would like to replace it with some logic which checks if a number begins with '0'. I'm aware of starts-with? for strings, is there a method for use with numbers?

I'm trying to do it this way as if I pass Integer/toOctalString an integer without a 0 it passes back a larger number. E.g. 2345 becomes 4451.

Thank you

Comment: So `a` should be of an integer type? The source representation of an integer is not part of its runtime representation, so it doesn't make sense to check "if a number begins with '0'".

Comment: I understand, however, I'm writing this to understand how to create error handling for octal numbers, when the intended is a number of base 8. For example, i would like to be able to change 023 to 23, but not 23 to 27.

Comment: When I say "it doesn't make sense", I mean that the necessary information to answer the question you're asking is not present at runtime, so what you're asking is impossible. At runtime, `023` is represented exactly the same as `(Integer/parseInt "10011" 2)`, and `23` is represented exactly the same as `(Integer/parseInt "10111" 2)`. You can't get back the representation that was used in the source code.

Comment: Oh right, is there a way to simply check if 'a' here starts with 0, or is that the point I'm missing?

Comment: You don't need a octal handling system. When you read in numbers that have a 0 prefix, like `023`, it becomes `19` since `(= 19 023) ;==> true` It's because `023` and `19` in code isn't numbers until it's read in and the reader converts the array of chars into a number. By the tmoe a number is read in the 0-prefix is gone since it was information to the reader. When it's a number it doesn't have a base anymore. Perhaps you want something that reads an octal string and turns it into a number?

Comment: @Nikhil That's the point you're missing: integers are not represented as strings. Assuming type `int`, the number 023 is stored in your computer's memory as four bytes that hold the binary value `00000000000000000000000000010011`, and the number 23 is stored in your computer's memory as four bytes that hold the binary value `00000000000000000000000000010111`. Given those two four-byte values, you can see that the question "does it start with 0" in the sense that you're asking it is meaningless.

Comment: @Sylwester Yes, that's exactly what I'm after in this case. 
Sam, I get what you mean now, thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 1):

It seems `read-string` can do this for you:

```
(read-string "023")
; ==> 19

(read-string "19")
; ==> 19
```

If you want to read octal without prefix you can simply add the zero before passing it:

```
(defn octal->integer [s]
  (read-string (str \0 s)))

(octal->integer "23")
; ==> 19
```

Answer (score 0):

When outputting numbers:

The built in `format` function does this nicely:

```
user> (format "%o" 19)
"23"
```

of course nothing about a number knows if it was originally provided in a particular format, though if you put it into a collection and store that information along with it, either directly or in metadata you can keep track of that.

---

As far as reading numbers is concerned:

Clojure numbers are Octal by default if they start with a leading zero

Just the usual warning that **clojure.core/read-string IS TOTALLY UNSAFE** to use on untrusted input. It will run code from the string at read time if not carefully managed.

**user clojure.edn/read-string instead**

They both will read an octal number for you just fine:

```
user> (clojure.edn/read-string "023")
19
user> (read-string "023")
19
```

And clojure.edn/read-string will refuse to p0wn your server:

```
user> (read-string "#=(println \"Pwning your server now\")")
Pwning your server now
nil

user> (clojure.edn/read-string "#=(println \"Pwning your server now\")")
RuntimeException No dispatch macro for: =  clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
```

So it's worth being in the habit of using clojure.edn for all data that it not actually part of your program.

---

PS: there is a dynamic var you can set to turn off the reader-eval feature of read string, and depending on it is an accident waiting to happen.